# Retrieve aggregations using Spring Data Elasticsearch Reactive Template

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

We are using Spring Data Elasticsearch Reactive Template

```
Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(queryBuilder)
                .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 10))
                .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("categories").field("category"))
                .build();

reactiveElasticsearchTemplate.search(searchQuery, documentType, IndexCoordinates.of(indexName))
```

In response we have `Flux<SearchHit<T>>` but there are no methods to retrieve aggregations.

How to retrieve the aggregations?

Answer (score 2):

The `ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate` has `aggregate` methods.

See the corresponding [API interface](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ReactiveSearchOperations.java#L189-L208)

There is no combination of the single entities in a flux and the aggregations in the reactive part.

Comment: Thank you, I also found this pull request https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/203

Comment: This PR is about parsing the aggregation data, but it only considers StringTerms and LongTerms buckets, but aggregations are much more complex. For Spring Data Elasticsearch to support parsing aggregations, we would need to handle far more cases of aggregations. So at the moments we just return the Elasticsearch aggregations.

Comment: So, in case we want to return both hits and aggregations, we need to call 2 methods which each will return `Flux<T>` and than to combine these 2 `Flux<T>` into 1 `Flux<T>`, is this correct?

Comment: `search` returns `Flux<SearchHit<T>>` and `aggregate` returns `Flux<Aggregation>`. The returned types a different, aggregation objects are no entities